# How to remove headers and footer from pdf file using pdfbox in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Pdf Parser to convert pdf to text.Below is my code to convert pdf to text file using java.
My PDF file contains Following Data:

```
    Data Sheet(Header)
    PHP Courses for PHP Professionals(Header)

   Networking Academy
    We live in an increasingly connected world, creating a global economy and a growing need for technical skills.  Networking Academy delivers information technology skills to over 500,000 students a year in more than 165 countries worldwide. Networking Academy students have the opportunity to participate in a powerful and consistent learning experience that is supported by high quality, online curricula and assessments, instructor training, hands-on labs, and classroom interaction. This experience ensures the same level of qualifications and skills regardless of where in the world a student is located.

    All copyrights reserved.(Footer).
```

Sample code:

```
public class PDF_TEST {
    PDFParser parser;
    String parsedText;
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
    PDDocument pdDoc;
    COSDocument cosDoc;
    PDDocumentInformation pdDocInfo;

    // PDFTextParser Constructor 
    public PDF_TEST() {
    }

    // Extract text from PDF Document
    String pdftoText(String fileName) {


        File f = new File(fileName);

        if (!f.isFile()) {

            return null;
        }

        try {
            parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(f));
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return null;
        }

        try {
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc); 
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                   if (cosDoc != null) cosDoc.close();
                   if (pdDoc != null) pdDoc.close();
               } catch (Exception e1) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }      

        return parsedText;
    }

    // Write the parsed text from PDF to a file
    void writeTexttoFile(String pdfText, String fileName) {


        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            pw.print(pdfText);
            pw.close();     
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //Extracts text from a PDF Document and writes it to a text file
    public static void test() {
        String args[]={"C://Sample.pdf","C://Sample.txt"};
        if (args.length != 2) {

            System.exit(1);
        }

        PDFTextParser pdfTextParserObj = new PDFTextParser();


        String pdfToText = pdfTextParserObj.pdftoText(args[0]);

        if (pdfToText == null) {

        }
        else {

            pdfTextParserObj.writeTexttoFile(pdfToText, args[1]);
        }
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        test();
    }
}
```

The above code works for extracting pdf to text.But my requirement is to ignore Header and Footer  and extract only content from pdf file.
Required output:

```
Networking Academy
        We live in an increasingly connected world, creating a global economy and a growing need for technical skills.  Networking Academy delivers information technology skills to over 500,000 students a year in more than 165 countries worldwide. Networking Academy students have the opportunity to participate in a powerful and consistent learning experience that is supported by high quality, online curricula and assessments, instructor training, hands-on labs, and classroom interaction. This experience ensures the same level of qualifications and skills regardless of where in the world a student is located.
```

Please suggest me how to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In general there is nothing special about header or footer texts in PDFs. It is possible to tag that material differently, but tagging is optional and the OP did not provide a sample PDF to check.

Thus, some manual work (or somewhat failure intensive image analysis) generally is necessary to find the regions on the pages for header, content, and footer material.

As soon as you have the coordinates for these regions, though, you can use the `PDFTextStripperByArea`which extends the `PDFTextStripper` to collect text by regions. Simply define a region for the page content using the largest rectangle including the content but excluding headers and footers, and after `pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc)` call `getTextForRegion` for the defined region.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use PDFTextStripperByArea to remove "Header" and "Footer" by pdf file.
Code in java using PDFBox.

 public String fetchTextByRegion(String path, String filename, int pageNumber) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(path + filename);
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        //Rectangle2D region = new Rectangle2D.Double(x,y,width,height);
        Rectangle2D region = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 100, 550, 700);
        String regionName = "region";
        PDFTextStripperByArea stripper;
        PDPage page = document.getPage(pageNumber + 1);
        stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
        stripper.addRegion(regionName, region);
        stripper.extractRegions(page);
        String text = stripper.getTextForRegion(regionName);
        return text;
    }
```